# Sharepoint custom webpart memory issue

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm using ".NET Memory Profiler" tool to analyze the memory allocation by w3wp process for a custom web part.

If I use "SharePoint Search Results" web part(out of the box Sharepoint webpart) in the page then the previously mentioned custom web part is not fully released.
Those two web parts do not have any connection between them, but still the memory issue happens. Does anybody has any idea why?

Please see the attached image:
1 - the page without the search result webpart
2 - the page with the search result webpart after allocation
3 - the page after release; as you can see, a bunch of objects were not disposed.

[image: Memory issue picture]

Comment: Are you using the SPWebPartManager or SPLimitedWebPartManager classes in your code?

Comment: SPLimitedWebPartManager it's being used for adding search results webpart. The custom webpart is added from master page.

Comment: are  you disposing the Web on the SPLimitedWebPartManager?

Comment: Yes. , I'm disposing the Web.

Comment: Can you try and profile with just the search web part see if anything looks different?

Comment: If I profile only the search web part in page, my assembly is not present in the profiler.

Comment: My hunch is that that class is causing the leak.  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jjameson/2008/04/09/memory-leak-in-splimitedwebpartmanager-a-k-a-idisposables-containing-idisposables/

Comment: Thanks Adam. The link is from 2008, but with Sharepoint, you never know. I'll give it a go and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Hey Adam, I've tried , and the webpart works alright. Do you have any other ideas?